# x86: Using rep and stosd to set value at memory location

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

An assembly program that uses string instructions to set the value of a range of 10 memory addresses to 0 using the `rep` instructions. I came up with an algorithm in my mind.

```asm
cld  
mov eax, 0  
mov ecx, 10  
rep stosd
```

But I am not pretty sure about it.

Comment: You are storing 10 double words (40 bytes), is that ok? And I think it is `repe stosd`.

Comment: You need to set the destination address.

Comment: Right, he/she forgot EDI.

Comment: Thankyou It's a 'she'.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez it's just `rep` for filling arrays, the `repe` would test the value as well as `ecx`.

Comment: This is what I had in mind :                                                                    rep repeats the stosd instruction which stores the value in eax(here = 0) and then increments edi . [edi]<--eax. and edi=edi +4(because we used cld instruction). After each stosd the value in ecx gets decremented until ecx becomes 0.

Comment: @Saumya Sahay: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: @zx485 Thankyou for clearing my doubts. :)

Comment: @SaumyaSahay you might use `repe cmpsb` or `repne cmpsb` for comparing strings, pointed to by `esi` and `edi`.

Comment: @Saumya Sahay: I added some commas to the code of your question to make it conforming to NASM syntax.